# setHasOptionsMenu(Boolean): Unit está deprecatado Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, deprecated

Tras una update de depedencias me sale el aviso de que `setHasOptionsMenu` está deprecatado

Dentro de los fragmentos que cargo menús adicionales

```kotlin
  override fun onCreateView(...): View {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando por la red, ahora para cargar los menús se debe hacer con `MenuProvider` dejo ejemplos de uso para `activity fragment` y `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

#### Activity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

   addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
      }

      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
        return true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

#### Fragment

```kotlin
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()

    //Same Activtiy declaration
    menuHost.addMenuProvider...
```

#### PreferenceFragmentCompat

```kotlin
val menuHost: MenuHost = requireHost() as MenuHost
//Same declaration with Fragment
```

#### Usando la interface MenuProvider

```kotlin
class FirstFragment : Fragment(), MenuProvider {
 
      override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
              val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
              menuHost.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
      }
 
      override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Add menu items here
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.second_menu, menu)
      }
 
      override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle the menu selection
            return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_clear -> {
                    // Do stuff...
                    true
                }
                R.id.menu_refresh -> {
                    // Do stuff...
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Solución basada de ese tweet: https://twitter.com/Codelaby/status/1558745982803869705?s=20&t=6ap1lh7Du3XjLP2DcEkxSQ